# Scala trait with generic self type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a trait that defines an action which is a glorified version of .copy(). which looks like this:

```
trait Optimize[T] {
    def optimize: T
}
```

and a bunch of classes that extend it like:

```
case class Account(field: String) extends Optimize[Account] {
    def optimize = this.copy(field = field.intern())
}
```

Is there a way to define a trait that requires a method optimize return the same type as self but doesn't require specifying a type when extending it? So I'd be able to write:

```
case class Account(field: String) extends Optimize {
    def optimize = this.copy(field = field.intern())
}
```

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Comment: Another way is to split it out into implicit style, so `optimize : T => T` and it's not a member, instead you can use it on a T when you have an `Optimize[T]` in scope. Then there can be no funny business where it returns a different type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

One way or another (abstract types) you *need* to tell `Optimize` what the return type of that function is.

Why? Because `Optimize` can be used in a type expression without specifying the concrete class, and there's no way for the compiler to know what type it will produce:

```
def someOtherMethod (a: Optimize) {
  val result = a.optimize // what is the type?
}
```

(in the case of an abstract type, the return type would be `a.T` or `Optimize#T` ... not very useful)

Comment: Thanks, apparently it can't be done. I wanted to do it simply because it feels weird to write class "A extends Trait[A]" and I thought there could be a way to avoid it. sd
I was thinking about type classes at first and it looks like it's one of the best solutions to this task in general. But in my particular case those optimize methods will have other optimizable fields and it will add too much clutter.
F-bounds don't help me because I still have to specify the type.
Specifying the type in case class is simply moving this declaration somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.type` as return value to refer to the implementor's type.

```
def optimize: this.type = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to avoid specifying a type parameter when extending, you can move the definition to a type member like this.

```
trait Optimize {
    type T
    def optimize: T
}

case class Account(field: String) extends Optimize {
    type T = Account
    def optimize = this.copy(field = field.intern())
}
```

But you just moved it from one place to another. Also, it's much better practice to parameterize the trait with a type parameter than to get type members involved.

What is the reason for doing this? Because your use case seems like a perfectly valid situation for a type parameter. Trait needs to be told what it is that optimize() returns, either via type parameter or type member.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
trait Ret[T]

trait A {
  def func(): Ret[_ <: A]
}

case class B() extends A {
  override def func(): Ret[B] = ???
}
```